# My UISearchBar in UISearchController disappear when I start searching. Why?

Tags: uisearchcontroller

This is how I setup my `UIsearchController`

```
private func setupSearchController() {
    let searchResultsController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(DBSearchOptionControllerIdentifier) as! DBSearchOptionController

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)

    let frame = searchController.searchBar.frame
    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, view.bounds.size.width, 44.0)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchBar.text = "mmm"
    view.bringSubviewToFront(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchBar.bringSubviewToFront(view)

}
```

This is how it looks after I initialise `UISearchController`:

[image]

This is how it looks when I start typing in UISearchBar:

[image]

**Why my search bar disappear?**

This is very interesting, because now when I stop the app, you can see, that it is there, indeed:-) So why it is not visible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made some testing and found a way:

UISearchBar definitely must be inserted into wrapper:

```
@IBOutlet weak var wrapperView: UIView!
```

...

```
wrapperView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

The result is following:

[image]